# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, command-prompt, dnx

I am trying to run this command "dnx ef migrations add setup" in the cmd of my project. I was returned with this error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500" and it states it fails to load one or more dependencies.

I am using VS2015 Project. Anyone knows what the error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this might be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739672/ssis-failed-on-installation-for-vs-2019/69085239#69085239